# Extending multiple classes in coffee-script

Tags: coffeescript

[The documentation](http://coffeescript.org) explain how to extend a class

```
class Zebra extends Animal
    ...
```

But how do I extend multiple classes? The following does **not** work

```
class Sidebar extends Controller, EventEmitter
    ...
```

But I wish it did. The JavaScript behind this is more than able to extend any number of classes using the `__extend` function, but is there a way to do it in coffee-script?

Comment: you can have a look at this discussion: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/452

Comment: suds... That doesn't bode well for me

Comment: JavaScript uses prototype inheritance... Behind the scene, extends uses the single property 'prototype' to create a chain... you can have "inherits" from multiple objects only if the objects are a prototype chain... e.g. Zebra could extends VegetarianAnimal and vegetarianAnimal extends Animal.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Guess I'll just answer my own question. The way I ended up handling this is extending all my classes from a class I call "*SuperClass*" (the name doesn't matter). From that class I can extend any number of classes. Anyway the class looks like this

```
moduleKeywords = ['included', 'extended']

class SuperClass
    @include: (obj) ->
        throw('include(obj) requires obj') unless obj
        for key, value of obj.prototype when key not in moduleKeywords
            @::[key] = value

        included = obj.included
        included.apply(this) if included
        @
```

Pretty much just stole it from [Spine](https://github.com/spine/spine). An example of a class extended from SuperClass:

```
class Sidebar extends SuperClass

    # Include some other classes
    @include Controller
    @include EventEmitter

    ###
    Constructor function
    ###
    constructor: ->
        # Call extended constructors
        Controller.call @
        EventEmitter.call @

        console.log 'Sidebar instantiated'
```

Notice that to call the inherited class' constructor the class function is called with `@`/`this` as context. I haven't needed to extend class functions yet, but I imagine it's very similar to calling the parent constructor:

```
someFunction: ->
    ExtendedClass::someFunction.call @
```

Please edit this post if I'm wrong. Also please excuse my lack of class inheritance terminology - I'm no expert

---

Update: One could also define a constructor for SuperClass that automatically called the constructor for all included classes on instantiation. That way you'd just need to call `super()` from the subclass. I haven't bothered with that though

Comment: I think calling super() won't work. You would need some kind of array storing the class of an `@include`d object. Which wouldn't work because you need to reset this same variable to `[]`.

Answer (score 6):

This is referred to as a [mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). CoffeeScript will never include them natively as you can read in the Classes section on [the CoffeeScript FAQ](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ). But there are various implementations out there, [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/993415), in the [Little Book](http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html), and [this one](https://github.com/kmalakoff/mixin) for JS seems to work with CoffeeScript Classes also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use little helper, which create proper prototype chain with correct call `super`.
Existing classes in chain not violated, uses theirs "projections"

https://gist.github.com/darrrk/75d6a6a4d431e7182888

```
virtual_class = (classes...)->
  classes.reduceRight (Parent, Child)->
    class Child_Projection extends Parent
      constructor: ->
        # Temporary replace Child.__super__ and call original `constructor`
        child_super = Child.__super__
        Child.__super__ = Child_Projection.__super__
        Child.apply @, arguments
        Child.__super__ = child_super

        # If Child.__super__ not exists, manually call parent `constructor`
        unless child_super?
          super

    # Mixin prototype properties, except `constructor`
    for own key  of Child::
      if Child::[key] isnt Child
        Child_Projection::[key] = Child::[key]

    # Mixin static properties, except `__super__`
    for own key  of Child
      if Child[key] isnt Object.getPrototypeOf(Child::)
        Child_Projection[key] = Child[key]

    Child_Projection
```

Example:

```
class My extends virtual_class A, B, C
```